# Modify the width, height and position of product variant drop-down for a Shopify Buy Button without disabling the iFrame

Tags: html, css, shopify

I need to alter the height of the product variant dropdown to exactly 42px (the same height as the buy button) and the width to exactly 80px. Additionally, instead of the product variant dropdown being positioned above the buy button, I need to be positioned directly beside the buy button to the left.

I've tried to find articles on how to do this within Shopify forums, but have yet to find one and I'm unsure where within the embedded code these elements are to change. Shopify doesn't offer customization support for their buy buttons either. I do not want to disable the iFrame.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/johnsmithh/eo4rzLwc/2/

Code:

```
<div id="product-component-1580935128063">
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy) {
    if (window.ShopifyBuy.UI) {
      ShopifyBuyInit();
    } else {
      loadScript();
    }
  } else {
    loadScript();
  }
  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = scriptURL;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
    script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
  }
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
      domain: 'missingnewyork.myshopify.com',
      storefrontAccessToken: '8ad1e9d2d113621e1e9785f5a84b7330',
    });
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function (ui) {
      ui.createComponent('product', {
        id: '4448713736258',
        node: document.getElementById('product-component-1580935128063'),
        moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
        options: {
  "product": {
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "calc(25% - 20px)",
          "margin-left": "20px",
          "margin-bottom": "50px"
        }
      },
      "button": {
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "color": "#000000",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#000000",
          "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
        },
        "background-color": "#ffffff",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
        },
        "border-radius": "5px"
      },
    },
      "option": {
          "display": "inline-block",
          "width": "20px",
      },  
    "contents": {
      "img": false,
      "title": false,
      "price": false
    },
    "text": {
    "outOfStock": "SOLD OUT"
    },    
  },
  "productSet": {
    "styles": {
      "products": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "margin-left": "-20px"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "modalProduct": {
    "contents": {
      "img": false,
      "imgWithCarousel": true,
      "button": false,
      "buttonWithQuantity": true
    },
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "100%",
          "margin-left": "0px",
          "margin-bottom": "0px"
        }
      },
      "button": {
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "color": "#000000",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#000000",
          "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
        },
        "background-color": "#ffffff",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
        },
        "border-radius": "5px"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "button": "ADD TO CART"
    }
  },
  "cart": {
    "styles": {
      "button": {
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "color": "#000000",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#000000",
          "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
        },
        "background-color": "#ffffff",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
        },
        "border-radius": "5px"
      },
      "title": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "header": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "lineItems": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "subtotalText": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "subtotal": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "notice": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "currency": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "close": {
        "color": "#ffffff",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }
      },
      "empty": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "noteDescription": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "discountText": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "discountIcon": {
        "fill": "#ffffff"
      },
      "discountAmount": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "cart": {
        "background-color": "#000000"
      },
      "footer": {
        "background-color": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "title": "CART",
      "empty": "YOUR CART IS EMPTY.",
      "notice": "Shipping and taxes are added at checkout.",    
    }
  },
  "toggle": {
    "styles": {
      "toggle": {
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "background-color": "#ffffff",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
        },
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "color": "#000000",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#000000"
        }
      },
      "iconPath": {
        "fill": "#000000"
      }
    }
  },
  "lineItem": {
    "styles": {
      "variantTitle": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "title": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "price": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "fullPrice": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "discount": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "discountIcon": {
        "fill": "#ffffff"
      },
      "quantity": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "quantityIncrement": {
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "border-color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "quantityDecrement": {
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "border-color": "#ffffff"
      },
      "quantityInput": {
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "border-color": "#ffffff"
      }
    }
  }
},
      });
    });
  }
})();
/*]]>*/
</script>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. What I would suggest is removing the iFrame altogether and styling it in a CSS file. It'd look something like this:

```
        moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
        options: {
       "product": {
         "iframe": false,
         ...
          }
       }
```

You can find more information about it [here](https://shopify.github.io/buy-button-js/advanced/), just skip to "Custom styling without iframes". There are some other alternatives, but I believe this one would be the best one to have full control as you wish.

Keep in mind that naturally it will mess up the pre-built CSS. [Here is an example I coded for you.](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/yLNKQbv)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for an answer that does not require removing the iFrame altogether.

Comment: Why is that? It's so much easier. I have styled it the way you want in 2 minutes. https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/yLNKQbv

Comment: What I'm seeing in the pen isn't correct. The drop down is not the same height as the buy button nor is it placed to the left of the button, it's still positioned above it. Heres a screenshot: https://ibb.co/wKJ2mbF And the reason I don't want to disable the iFrame is because I love all of the original styling, it's just these few position and size changes I need to alter.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of choice in this case, I could be wrong but I think it's the only available option. It's showing differently on yours because you're on Mac, you just need to apply the [CSS vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)...

Comment: The point is that now you have the option to customize the CSS in whichever way you want.